# Commuting Exponential Matrices

Tags: analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Let $x(t)=\exp(tA)\exp(tB)$ and $y(t)=\exp(t(A+B))$. 

 Show that if $AB=BA$ then $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ satisfy the same initial value problem for ODEs and therefore must be equal.

$A, B$ square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: (1) *What ODEs do $x$ and $y$ fulfill*? Compute $x'$ and $y'$, try to find the given terms for $x$ and $y$ in your computed expressions. Write down a differential equation for $x$ and $y$? Are they equal?

(2) Compute $x(0)$ and $y(0)$. Are these values equal?

Comment: Okay so we can write x'=(A+B)x and y'=(A+B)y, which are clearly the same ODE. And then x(0)=A+B=y(0). Thanks :)

Comment: @Steve You have $x(0)=y(0)=I$