# Quick Fact Check if $A$ and $B$ Commute, $\exp((A+B)t)= \exp(At)\cdot\exp(Bt)$?

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

If $A$ and $B$ Commute, $\exp((A+B)t)= \exp(At)\cdot\exp(Bt)$? is this statement true?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449354/commuting-exponential-matrices?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean exp(At+Bt)=exp(At)exp(Bt)? (If so, the t is unnecessary.)

Comment: Yes, the statement is true. Note: as a matter of fact, this is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Can you explain why the converse is true, i.e. why $\exp(t(A + B)) = \exp(tA)\exp(tB)$ for all $t \geq 0$ implies that $A$ and $B$ commute?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: if so, i would appreciate a comment or answer to my post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991471/if-expta-b-expta-exptb-for-all-t-geq-0-then-a-b-commute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact the case.  For a thorough explanation, please see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568450/m-n-in-bbb-r-n-times-n-show-that-emn-emen-given-mn-nm).  It's only a mouse click away!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

if $A\cdot B=B\cdot A$

then  $e^{A+B}=e^{A}\cdot e^{B}$

now multiply both side by $t$

we have

$e^{At+Bt}$,

you can apply same rule  for this too

there is   question related to matrix expoenntial

[Commuting in Matrix Exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370817/commuting-in-matrix-exponential)

Comment: Do you mean multiply $A$ and $B$ by $t$?

Comment: he has done like this,$t$ is on the  exponential part right?

Comment: huh? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @anon is my answer mistake?

Comment: No, I just think instead of saying "multiply both side[s] by $t$" (which would result in $e^{A+B}t=e^A*e^Bt$) you should say "multiply $A$ and $B$ by $t$." Although there is the issue that you are simply stating the desired conclusion without proof.

Comment: yes yes sorry,English is  not my  native language

Comment: i have shown  about commute matrix exponential